# How can I figure out GCP JupyterLab web frozen issue when loading/running some specific notebooks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I just start running GCP JupyterLab. The website keeps frozen when loading or running some Jupyter notebook. Sometimes I got message which asked me to wait or exit. Sometimes, I got crashed website. I could not figure out the reason. Could anyone conduct me to fix this issue? Below are what I have done.

1. stopped/restarted the instance, and then open the JupyterLab website. Not working. I can close the notebook at the short moment when I logged in the JupyterLab website. But, when I load the notebook again, the web became frozen or crashed.
2. Created a new instance. I got the same issue while loading some specific Jupyter Notebook. I believed that something wrong with the notebook, but I am unable to fix it.

Any further help and advice would be appreciated.